# Manipulating 2D matrix using numpy boolean indexing takes a long time

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, numpy-ndarray

I've generated a huge amount of random data like so:

```
ndata = np.random.binomial(1, 0.25, (100000, 1000))
```

which is a 100,000 by 1000 matrix(!)

I'm generating new matrix where for each row, each column is true if the mean of all the columns beforehand (minus the expectancy of bernoulli RV with p=0.25) is greater than equal some epsilon.

like so:

```
def true_false_inequality(data, eps, data_len):
    return [abs(np.mean(data[:index + 1]) - 0.25) >= eps for index in range(data_len)]
```

After doing so I'm generating a 1-d array (finally!) where each column represents how many true values I had in the same column in the matrix, and then I'm dividing every column by some number (exp_numer = 100,000)

```
def final_res(data, eps):
    tf = np.array([true_false_inequality(data[seq], eps, data_len) for seq in range(exp_number)])
    percentage = tf.sum(axis=0)/exp_number
    return percentage
```

Also I have 5 different epsilons which I iterate from to get my final result 5 times.
(epsilons =  [0.001, 0.1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.025])

**My code does work**, but it takes a long while for 100,000 rows by 1000 columns, I know I can make it faster by exploring the numpy functionality a little bit more but I just don't know how.

Comment: It looks like you are working with a cummulative mean, right?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem true, but I guess using np.mean() will be the same as just doing so my self if you're implying that I should do so (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the whole calculation with vectorized operations on the full data array:

```
mean = np.cumsum(data, axis=1) / np.arange(1, data.shape[1]+1)
condition = np.abs(mean - 0.25) >= eps
percentage = condition.sum(axis=0) / len(data)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, data.shape will always be 1, 1000 (in the true_false_inequality function), note that I specified that for each row, each corresponding column is true if the mean of all the columns beforehand.

Comment: @MercyDude I misunderstood your question, please see my updated answer, it should address the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the *cummulative* mean with:

```
np.cumsum(ndata, axis=0).sum(axis=1) / np.arange(1, 100001)
```

so we can optimize the `true_false_inequality` to:

```
def true_false_inequality(data, eps, data_len):
    cummean = np.cumsum(ndata, axis=0).sum(axis=1) / np.arange(1, data_len)
    return abs(cummean - 0.25) >= eps
```

Or like @a_guest suggests, we can first sum up the elements, and then calculate the cumulative sum:

```
def true_false_inequality(data, eps, data_len):
    cummean = ndata.sum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=0) / np.arange(1, 100001)
    return abs(cummean - 0.25) >= eps
```

Comment: It's even more optimized if you first sum along `axis=1` and then compute the `cumsum` since that reduces the number of required additions by the column count and similarly the required memory for the temporary array coming out of `cumsum`.

Comment: But in the true_false_inequality I calculate the mean for a single row! note that you accessed ndata, but the function only gets the data param which is as stated a single row from the big matrix.